# Как узнать конфигурацию Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте, есть ли способ определить какие ключи использовались в configure при сборке.

Иногда надо пересобрать Qt, чтобы было также, как есть, но внести изменение.

Comment: нет такого способа, не раз задавали такой вопрос на qt-форуме, разработчики, что-то отвечают невразумительное, ибо понятно, что это должно быть, а нет